Issues with Laravel Sanctum Authentication in a Chrome Extension
I’m facing difficulties with using Laravel Sanctum for user authentication in a Chrome Extension. Despite following standard setup procedures, the authentication isn't working as expected.
What I’ve Tried:
Configured Laravel Sanctum settings.
Set up headers and ensured cookies are included in requests.
Verified that cookies are being sent.
Expected Result:
I expected that the extension’s requests would be authenticated successfully.
Current Issue:
The requests are not being authenticated properly.
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated
